# Almost complete convergence

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory

In the book nonparametric functional data analysis, page 232, i don't understand why:
The almost complete convergence of $Y_n$ to $l\ne 0$ implies that **there**
**exists** some $\delta > 0$ (choose for instance $\delta = l/2$) such that

$$\sum_{i\ge 0}\mathsf{P}(|Y_n| \le \delta) < \infty.$$
Cordially.

Comment: What does almost complete convergence mean?

Comment: almost complete convergence of (Yn) to Y MEAN for each δ > 0:           
 $$∑n∈N P(|Yn-Y | >δ)<∞.$$

Comment: the sum over n∈N,  of P(|Yn−Y|>δ) is finite.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $l>0$. Since
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(|Y_n|\le l/2)&=\mathsf{P}(-l/2\le Y_n\le l/2)\\
&\le \mathsf{P}(Y_n\le l-l/2)\le \mathsf{P}(|Y_n-l|\ge l/2),
\end{align}

$$
\sum_{n\ge 1}\mathsf{P}(|Y_n|\le l/2)\le \sum_{n\ge 1}\mathsf{P}(|Y_n-l|\ge l/2)<\infty.
$$